# Know when data is sent

Tags: c++, networking, winsock

I believe know that call send or WSASend in nonblocking mode add simply data in a internal buffer, but how know when data is really sent ? My goal is to display a progress bar.

Comment: In my answer (which I deleted), I was not interpreting correctly what you were wanting.  And this might not be it either, so it's just a comment.  With a non-blocking socket, I believe you will get a WSAEWOUDBLOCK from the send call if the send buffer is full.  And if the send return value is less than the total given, you need to call send again with the remaining data.  So if your send buffer is, for example, set at 128K, then you could measure the progress you are making and generate the progress bar information from that.

Comment: I tried but change the send buffer size don't works correctly, I followed this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145871/calculating-socket-upload-speed and it works ! Thank you !

Comment: What precisly do you mean with "sent" ? If you've got a somewhat smart card that's doing buffering itself, do you count the moment that the OS hands the data to the network card, or the moment that the data hits the wire? Things get even trickier with stuff like VMware

Comment: I want the "sent" is near of the "received" of the other application. But the issue is resolved with the help of this topic : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145871/calculating-socket-upload-speed

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Boost.Asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html) (if it's feasible for you to change). It can perform async or sync sending and receiving. When sending asyncronously you can register a function that will be called when the send is complete.

Comment: Thank you, but I must use directly winsock.